# ANDROID-How do retrieve data when the user remember only some letters in a data row and not the entire value?

Tags: android, database

**in my main activity:**

```
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Aadolf - a baby boy name meaning " + " 'Strong wolf'");
                      mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Aaron - a baby boy name meaning " + " 'Father of many nations'");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Abel - a baby boy name meaning " + " 'Breathing'");
          mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Abigail - a baby girl name meaning" + " 'My father rejoices'"); 
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Abilane - a baby girl name meaning" + " 'A plain'");
```

I have this line of code in my database the select a query:

```
   String sql = "";
    sql += "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
    sql += " WHERE " + fieldObjectName + " LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'";
    sql += " ORDER BY " + fieldObjectId + " DESC";
    sql += " LIMIT 0,5";
```

in this part i'm using this symbol "%":

```
 sql += " WHERE " + fieldObjectName + " LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'";
```

to call the name when the user type a letter but when the user type a letter (example: A) all the name with have a letter A in their name will appears.

**Question:**
The user only remember the first name of the person using the first letter 
(example: Aadolf) the user type the letter A in edit box and some name will appeared starting with the letter A itself.

Comment: Just don't add the `%` to the beginning: `field LIKE 'Ab%'`

Comment: i already did that and the result is the same

Comment: @code143 as @323go said if you want to search results from data where name starts with A then use `'A%'` and if want to search where name contains A then `'%A%'`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
 + " Like '" + searchTerm + "%'";
```